# What is idle mode in Android

Tags: android

What is idle mode in android? Is it when my phone's screen is off or is it when no application is in foreground or something else?

Actually I have got a requirement, where some power management scripts need to be run once the phone is in Idle mode.

Comment: Look this is the documentation for the BroadcastReceivers https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html that should give you the basis for what you are looking for and then for your IDLE or Doze concern you should check the WakefullBroadcastReceiver https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/WakefulBroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 5):

According to the [developer docs](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html#testing_doze) IDLE means that the phone is on sleep. Doze mode is for Android 6 and later.

Answer (score 2):

IDLE mode is when your phone is ON but you are not using the phone and the screen is off (sleep mode). Also IDLE mode for some phones can also mean POWER ON mode, whenever your using the phone, its in IDLE mode.

> Actually I have got a requirement , where some power management scripts are to be run once the phone is in Idle mode.

I don't understand that part of your question, can you clarify.

Comment: Well, these are some scripts where in CPU consumption ,battery usage etc. of device is monitored under various modes one of which is Idle mode.

Comment: Does this imply, say if I am playing an audio file and my screen is off, it is in idle mode ?

Comment: I would think so, according to the definition I posted above. If I were you I would do a little more research just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

simply yes idle state is when you are not using the device.

> The IDLE state is When an Android device is left without being used, first it will dim the screen, then turn off the screen, and finally, turn off the CPU. This prevents the device battery from quickly being drained.[Read further.](https://medium.com/mindorks/you-have-to-know-more-about-doze-mode-3d80f016f8ad)

If you need to handle some work in the background while the device is in idle mode you can use [WorkManager](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/workmanager-basics-beba51e94048), As it provides some helpful [Constrains](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/Constraints).